# "Undefined reference to" error even function is declared and defined

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

I have these 2 c file and a header file. All these files are built by a `Makefile`.

**mysql_storage.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>

#if 1
typedef enum {
        STORAGE_OK = 0,
        STORAGE_NO_SUCH_USER,
        STORAGE_INVALID_PASSWORD,
        STORAGE_ALREADY_EXISTS,
        STORAGE_OTHER_ERROR/* Error that isn't caused by user input, such as 
                               a database that is unreachable. log() will be 
                               used for the exact error message */
} storage_status_t;

typedef enum
{
    MYSQL_PASS_CHECK_ONLY = -1,
    MYSQL_PASS_UNKNOWN = 0,
    MYSQL_PASS_WRONG,
    MYSQL_PASS_OK
} mysql_pass_st;
#endif

static void mysql_storage_init( void );
static void mysql_storage_deinit( void );
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_load(const char *password );
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_check_pass( const char *nick, const char *password );
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_save( int overwrite );
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_remove( const char *nick, const char *password );
```

**mysql_storage.c**

```
#include "mysql_storage.h"

MYSQL *mysql;

static void mysql_storage_init( void ) {
    if (mysql_init(mysql) == NULL)
        fprintf( stderr, "Can not initialize MySQL. Configuration won't be saved.");

    if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, "localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", NULL, 3306, NULL, 0))
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\nConfiguration won't be saved.", mysql_error(mysql));

    if (mysql_select_db(mysql, "DATABASENAME"))
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\nConfiguration won't be saved.", mysql_error(mysql));
}
static void mysql_storage_deinit( void ) {
    if(mysql!=NULL) 
        mysql_close(mysql);
}
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_check_pass( const char *nick, const char *password ){    return STORAGE_OTHER_ERROR;}
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_load(const char *password ){    return STORAGE_OTHER_ERROR;}
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_save( int overwrite ){    return STORAGE_OTHER_ERROR;}
static storage_status_t mysql_storage_remove( const char *nick, const char *password ){    return STORAGE_OTHER_ERROR;}
```

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "mysql_storage.h"

    int main(){
        // connect mysql
        mysql_storage_init();
        // check a password
        printf("check password: %d\n:", mysql_storage_check_pass("hello", "world"));
        // close mysql
        mysql_storage_deinit();
    }
```

Lastly the **Makefile**

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I.
LIBS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl -lglib-2.0 -L.
CC=gcc

all: main
clean:
        rm main  *.o
main: mysql_storage.o main.o 
        $(CC)  main.o mysql_storage.o $(LIBS) -o main
.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

When I make, I get this error.

```
gcc  main.o mysql_storage.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl -lglib-2.0 -L. -o main
main.o: In function `main':
/home/shiplu/projects/mysql_interface/main.c:8: undefined reference to `mysql_storage_init'
/home/shiplu/projects/mysql_interface/main.c:11: undefined reference to `mysql_storage_check_pass'
/home/shiplu/projects/mysql_interface/main.c:15: undefined reference to `mysql_storage_deinit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see I am linking `main.o` and `mysql_storage.o`. So it should not throw undefined reference error. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared your functions `mysql_storage_init` as `static`, meaning they have **internal [linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_%28software%29)** -- this means they are not visible to other translation units.

Since you need to call them from other object files, you should instead declare them to have **external linkage** by omitting the `static` keyword in their declarations and definitions.  The prototypes in the header file may optionally declare them `extern`, but that is not required, since the linkage is external by default.

Comment: aha!. I dind't know that. But I am think how some other project is declaring static members and getting called.

Comment: If I create static functions and put the function pointer in a non static structure, can I call it from outside where the structure will be declared as `extern`?

Comment: Yes, if you create `static` functions, you can pass around function pointers to them and call them via the function pointers anywhere.  But you can only *create* the function pointer from within the same translation unit.

Comment: small caveat - on Windows if you declare a function as `static` it *may* change it's call semantics from __far to __near making it problematic (or even impossible) for such a function to be called from another translation unit. Unless you explicitly need a function to be local to that one .obj file you should not have a need to declare it as `static`

Answer (score 3):

You mysql_storage.c functions are defined as `static`, which means they are not visible outside of the file. Remove `static` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am still noob in C

Answer (score 3):

The `static` keyword for a function means this function will have the scope of **this .obj file only**, which is probably not what you expect. Remove the `static` keyword for function definitions and declarations (both .h and .cpp files)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was it. Not it compiles okay.

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyword static before your functions ensures that they are only visible within the compilation unit that they are defined. If you remove the static keyword from your functions you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to use functions in different compilation units, you should not declare them static.

Comment: Thats a nice tip. But I think it should go as a comment.

Comment: No, it is direct answer to the question. That is why linking fails.

Comment: It's phrased as a tip. Notice how much more information is provided by the four answers that were entered before yours.